# how to convert textbox format to money with comma sepration format ( like 100,236,563 ) in c#?

Tags: c#, format, currency

I have textbox and I need to convert format of that to curency and money format with comma seprator ( like `12,654,500` ) can anybody help me ??

```
private void txtMuchMoney_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the format you want, with four digits between the commas?

Comment: So your textbox mask should be `$000,000,000`

Comment: Why don't you first try to google the problem. It took me like 2 seconds to get it. First link leading to a detailed MSDN article

Answer (score 1):

Use this mask:

```
$000,000,000
```

Refer to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on masks.

> `$` : Currency symbol. The actual character displayed will be the currency symbol appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.
>
> `,` : Thousands placeholder. The actual display character used will be the thousands placeholder appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.

So, you might also want to set the FormatProvider property if you not get the desired behavior out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MaskedTextbox` and set the `Mask` property to `00,0000,000`.

Comment: Why don't you first try to google the problem. It took me like 2 seconds to get it. First link leading to a detailed MSDN article.

Comment: @user853710 that was supposed to be below the question, I presume.

Comment: I thought I am the only person who drinks in broad daylight :) :)  I am not alone :)  :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a MaskedTextBox instead 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx
the mask property value should simply be 00,0000,000