# Visual Basic How To Only Allow Integer Inputs?

Tags: vb.net, validation, input, integer

I have a quick question about a problem and i'm sure you guys will find it very easy to solve but i'm having some trouble with it. I'm very new to using visual basic and I'm trying to restrict a user input so that it will only allow the user to input integers and wanted to ask if you guys could possibly give me an example piece of code on how to do this?

I have looked around for solutions to this problem however, they all seem to incorporate text boxs or are very complex and too difficult for me to understand

Here's the basics my input that I want to restrict to only integer inputs so you guys can see what I am trying to work with:

```
Dim key As Integer
Console.Writeline("Please enter a number")
key = Console.ReadLine()
if key > 1 do this...
if key < 10 do this...
```

I appreciate any help you guys can provide for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Integer.TryParse`... More information [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim key As Integer
Console.Writeline("Please enter a number")

If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine,key) Then
   'Your conditions..
End If
```

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ why is it a shame? The OP posted a problem ***with code in question***.

Comment: Of course there's nothing wrong with the question itself. But even a little googling would have revealed the answer.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ `I have looked around for solutions to this problem however, they all seem to incorporate text boxs or are very complex and too difficult for me to understand` evidently he needed a push...

Comment: Yeah, the OP seems to be a beginner. But StackOverflow is *unfortunately* (no sarcasm; I regret it) not a place for such stuff... I agree he might have trouble converting code from C# to VB/Difficulty to understand code written for a TextBox,etc... You forgot to mention that if the condition evaluates to `true`, the input is an integer and not, if it turns out to be `false` :)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ it is interesting you can say that. Maybe I should just visit a few of **your post** and say the same thing? Here's one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722882/how-to-convert-textbox-format-to-money-with-comma-sepration-format-like-100-23/35723147#35723147 . I would reconsider your conclusions and look before saying something as you did :) The question here could have been a Google search as well, but guess what, you answered it...

Comment: In the past, StackOverflow was more a real site on which people offers help illustrating with their knowledges, instead of criticize, downvote, flag, or discuss with others, etc. +1 for @Codexer's answer.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Rep w. :p

Comment: @Codexer: [status-guilty]

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't mean to spark anything here lol. Was just a dude looking for some help and I appreciate the help Codexer ^_^

Comment: @SeanCampbell you didn't do anything man! Your welcome as well, glad I could help you!